# Writing a "HoC factory function factory" for generic React context consumers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

Currently I have a context called `ExploreContext` that I access by injecting the respective props into a particular component using a HoC factory function which kinda looks as follows:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Optionalize<T extends K, K> = Omit<T, keyof K>;

export type WithExploreContextProps = { exploreContext: IExploreContextStore };

export function withExploreContext<P extends WithExploreContextProps = WithExploreContextProps>(
    WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>
) {
    const displayName = WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || "Component";

    return class ComponentWithContext extends Component<Optionalize<P, WithExploreContextProps>> {
        public static displayName = `withExploreContext(${displayName})`;

        public render() {
            return (
                <Consumer>{(context) => <WrappedComponent {...this.props as P} exploreContext={context} />}</Consumer>
            );
        }
    };
}
```

This one works perfectly fine, but I was considering writing a generic factory function to create such HoC factories and reduce code duplication. What's important is that I wanted to be able to not call the injected context just `context`, but rather give it a more specific name. Hence I came up with the following solution:

```
export function createWithContext<WithProps, ContextStore>(
    ConsumerComponent: ExoticComponent<ConsumerProps<ContextStore>>,
    contextKey: keyof WithProps
) {
    return <P extends WithProps = WithProps>(WrappedComponent: ComponentType<P>) => {
        return class ComponentWithContext extends Component<Optionalize<P, WithProps>> {
            public render() {
                return (
                    <ConsumerComponent>
                        {(context) => {
                            const props: P & WithProps = { ...(this.props as P), [contextKey]: context };
                            return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
                        }}
                    </ConsumerComponent>
                );
            }
        };
    };
}
```

This particular implementation allows me to write the following quite easily:

```
export const withExploreContext = createWithContext<WithExploreContextProps, IExploreContextStore>(
    Consumer,
    "exploreContext"
);
```

which is even statically checked. I was curious though, whether there exists a more elegant way to implement such a "HoC factory function factory". Especially the necessity for the explicit `IExploreContextStore` as the second type parameter is too verbose for me since I create the context types as follows:

```
const { Consumer, Provider } = createContext<IExploreContextStore>({} as IExploreContextStore);
```

Any better solutions to simplify the `createWithContext` function?